# Vuejs: How to get computed property in created hook

Tags: vue.js, computed-properties

Is it possible to get computed property value in created hook? My current implementation doesn’t work. My understanding is created hook would be called first which would call my async method and async method needs the computed property, but by the time computed property becomes available the created hook has already been executed with the “undefined” parameter.

Please suggest how can i make computed property available to created hook method.

```
created() {
        this.fetchPropertyOptions();
},
computed: {
    propertyList() {
        return this.data.value;
    },
},
methods: {
    async fetchPropertyOptions() {
        this.propertyOptionsMap = await api.GetOptions(this.propertyList);
    },
}
```

Comment: `this.data.value` should be `this.value`

Comment: That was a typo, but that's not the issue. The question is how we can access the computed property in created hook?? and also why its down voted :(

Comment: Try using `mounted()` rather than `created()`?

Comment: yes, i did but it's also not working :(

Comment: @zubairm - it works for me: https://codepen.io/JosephSilber/pen/erZqYW

Comment: Thanks all for your help, Setting up a watcher on the property worked for me

Comment: Could anyone please suggest why my question is down-voted :(

Comment: upvoted, I just ran across this problem.

Answer (score 15):

The Vue component creation goes through different lifecycles. There's an excellent diagram in the [lifecycle diagram section](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) of the documentation.

Reading the above mentioned diagram from top to bottom, you notice the `created` hook that you use in your example. It is called directly after `Init injections & reactivity`. This is where e.g. the `props`, `data` & `computed` are initialised. Right after that, the `created` lifecycle method is called.

As a practical example, the codepen [Joseph Silber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/825568/joseph-silber) linked in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50012712/vuejs-how-to-get-computed-property-in-created-hook#comment87042967_50012712) shows the successful usage of a computed property in the `created` method.

In fact, the only lifecycle method that can't use the `injections & reactivity` is `beforeCreated`. All other lifecycle methods, e.g. `mounted`, `updated` and even `beforeDestroy` & `destroyed` have access to it.

Comment: I stepped through the code and created gets called before the first computed call. So I'm not sure what you're saying is correct.